# How to use custom html with link_to while specifying a 'method:'

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to render the following html :

```
<a href="<%= INSERT ARTICLE PATH WITH DELETE METHOD HERE %>" class="float-right action-button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">
    <%= image_tag("delete", size: "16x16") %>
  </button>
</a>
```

I tried this with no success:

```
<%= link_to(@article, method: :delete, class: "float-right action-button") do %>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">
    <%= image_tag("delete", size: "16x16") %>
  </button>
<%= end %>
```

And i get the following error :

```
SyntaxError in ArticlesController#index
C:/Sites/anais-coaching/app/views/articles/index.html.erb:34: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end ...eze;@output_buffer.append=( end );@output_buffer.safe_append... ... ^ C:/Sites/anais-coaching/app/views/articles/index.html.erb:43: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' '.freeze; end ^ C:/Sites/anais-coaching/app/views/articles/index.html.erb:47: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' C:/Sites/anais-coaching/app/views/articles/index.html.erb:49: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

I think my problem is I don't know how to use 'link_to xxx do'.
Thanks !

Comment: Please provide the error you get

Comment: @Vishal I added it

Comment: @'Mikhail Katrin' How do I specify this in the link to ? @Article.index ?

Comment: Like this `<%= link_to 'some caption', controller: :articles_controller, action: :delete, id; @article.id %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
<%= link_to @article, method: :delete,, data: {confirm:'Are you sure?' }, class: "float-right action-button") do %>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">
    <%= image_tag("delete", size: "16x16") %>
  </button>
<%= end %>
```

with this

```
<%= link_to @article, method: :delete, data: {confirm:'Are you sure?' }, class: "float-right action-button" do %>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">
    <%= image_tag("delete", size: "16x16") %>
  </button>
<% end %>
```

You don't need to add <%= %> for `end` .Let me know if error is resolved or not.
Please check [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) for link_to .

Comment: Thank you for your anwser: I copy pasted the code and I get a syntax error : https://pastebin.com/ZLgwRpTc

Comment: Please up vote my answer. if it is helpful to you :). it will also helpful for other users.

Comment: Updated my answer, please copy paste it.

Comment: It worked, you added a wrong ')' at the end maybe change it for helping others ! Also I am not able to up vote your answer with my current reputation :( Sorry !

Comment: Corrected my answer. You can up vote answer , because you posted questoin. you can also accept answer.

Comment: I accepted your anwser but when I try to up vote I get 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'

Comment: @LéoColetta Thank you so much for accepting my answer :) .